# How to add animation when state changes in react?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, animation

I have the following code which changes states after 3 seconds. I'm trying to add animation when state change. I've made a separate animation but having a problem linking both.
My animation -

```
<div class="wave wave5"></div>
<div class="wave wave4"></div>
<div class="wave wave3"></div>
<div class="wave wave2"></div>
<div class="wave wave1"></div>
<div class="wave wave0"></div>
--------------------------------
.wave{
  position:absolute;
  top:calc((100% - 30px)/2);
  left:calc((100% - 30px)/2);
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  background: url('https://c4.wallpaperflare.com/wallpaper/755/29/195/chun-lo-tiger-japanese-art-samurai-demon-hd-wallpaper-thumb.jpg');
  background-attachment:fixed;
  background-position:center center;
}
.wave0{
  z-index:2;
  background-size:auto 106%;
  animation:w 1s forwards;
}
.wave1{
  z-index:3;
  background-size:auto 102%;
  animation:w 1s .2s forwards;
}
.wave2{
  z-index:4;
  background-size:auto 104%;
  animation:w 1s .4s forwards;
}
.wave3{
  z-index:5;
  background-size:auto 101%;
  animation:w 1s .5s forwards;
}
.wave4{
  z-index:6;
  background-size:auto 102%;
  animation:w 1s .8s forwards;
}
.wave5{
  z-index:7;
  background-size:auto 100%;
  animation:w 1s 1s forwards;
}
@keyframes w{
  0%{
    top:calc((100% - 30px)/2);
    left:calc((100% - 30px)/2);
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
  }
  100%{
    top:calc((100% - 300px)/2);
    left:calc((100% - 300px)/2);
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
  }
}
```

App component

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      images: [
        "https://picsum.photos/200/300/?image=523",
        "https://picsum.photos/200/300/?image=524",
        "https://picsum.photos/200/300/?image=525",
        "https://picsum.photos/200/300/?image=526"
      ],
      selectedImage: "https://picsum.photos/200/300/?image=523",
      in: 0
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.setState(prevState => {
        if (prevState.in === 3) {
          return {
            in: 0,
            selectedImage: this.state.images[0]
          };
        } else {
          return {
            in: prevState.in + 1,
            selectedImage: this.state.images[prevState.in + 1]
          };
        }
      });
    }, 3000);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <img  src={this.state.selectedImage} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Code -https://codesandbox.io/s/react-image-change-0eduy?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Animation - https://codepen.io/354erytu/pen/OJVNYKQ

Comment: please post the code that changes state. You can use `componentDidUpdate` react function, this is called every time the component updates states

Comment: I've updated the question.

Comment: You can put `key=this.state.selectedImage` on the root div

Comment: @gaditzkhori I tried this but images start taking delays before displaying.

Comment: well I think it has noting to do with react. it is css. notice it happens on sanbox on the first image as well

Answer (score 0):

You try to use the state for re-render the css in DOM for information that the DOM already has. You should use a the trick of giving a new css at each render, **but one css change nothing** on the visual **only the classname name** in DOM.

You can find the code here : 
https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-tharp-j4px4?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      in: 0,
      enableWave: true
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.setState(prevState => {
        if (prevState.in % 2 === 0) {
          return {
            in: prevState.in + 1,
            enableWave: false
          };
        } else {
          return {
            in: prevState.in + 1,
            enableWave: true
          };
        }
      });
    }, 1500);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div style={{ display: this.state.enableWave ? "block" : "none" }}>
          <div className="wave wave5" />
          <div className="wave wave4" />
          <div className="wave wave3" />
          <div className="wave wave2" />
          <div className="wave wave1" />
          <div className="wave wave0" />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't do anything. It neither has that wavy animation nor does image change.

Comment: @Anupamkushwaha : I ve updated the code for showing the wave animation. But you will have to adapt it for your need.
I removed the image change, cause I don t need it : my code purpose is to show you the react mechanism with the DOM.